# Async / Await & Meteor code must always run within a Fiber

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

I'm getting the "Meteor code must always run within a Fiber" with some very simple code.

```
const notif = async (userId, notifs) => {
  try {
    console.log('Notif Function Start');
    const template = await Assets.getText('email-new-appointment-client.html');
    return 'sent';
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'notif functions', error);
  }
};
```

notif is a function called from within a Meteor method. No callbacks involved, no 3rd party promise libraries.

Even running the following in the same function is causing fiber errors:

```
Email.send({
  to: uEmail,
  from: 'fake@email.com',
  subject: notifs.title,
  html: notifs.body,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed "presets": ["es2015", "es2016", "stage-0", "react"], from my .bablerc file and the errors here went away.

Comment: Works for me, removing "presets" : ["stage-1"]